# how to use applicative validation using languageext?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, applicative, language-ext

I am trying to port an example using applicative validation with the teaching-lib [LaYumba](https://github.com/la-yumba/functional-csharp-code) to [LanguageExt](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext).

Here is the LaYumba Code (works as expected):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using FluentAssertions;
using LaYumba.Functional;
using Xunit;
using static LaYumba.Functional.F;

namespace DemoTests._1_LaYumbaDemo
{
    public class Demo
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Sum_validation()
        {
            // Arrange
            Func<int, int, int, int> sum = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;

            Func<int, Validation<int>> onlyPositive = i
                => i > 0
                    ? Valid(i)
                    : Error($"Number {i} is not positive.");

            Validation<int> AddNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
            {
                return Valid(sum) // returns int -> int -> int -> int
                    .Apply(onlyPositive(a)) // returns int -> int -> int
                    .Apply(onlyPositive(b)) // returns int -> int
                    .Apply(onlyPositive(c)); // returns int
            }

            // Act
            var result = AddNumbers(1, 2, 3);

            // Assert
            result.Match(
                _ => true.Should().BeFalse(),
                x => x.Should().Be(6));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Sum_validation_with_failures()
        {
            // Arrange
            Func<int, int, int, int> sum = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;

            Func<int, Validation<int>> onlyPositive = i
                => i > 0
                    ? Valid(i)
                    : Error($"Number {i} is not positive.");

            Validation<int> AddNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
            {
                return Valid(sum) // returns int -> int -> int -> int
                    .Apply(onlyPositive(a)) // returns int -> int -> int
                    .Apply(onlyPositive(b)) // returns int -> int
                    .Apply(onlyPositive(c)); // returns int
            }

            // Act
            var result = AddNumbers(-1, -2, -3);

            // Assert
            result.Match(
                errors => errors.Select(x => x.Message)
                    .Should()
                    .Contain("Number -1 is not positive.")
                    .And.Contain("Number -2 is not positive.")
                    .And.Contain("Number -3 is not positive."),
                x => true.Should().BeFalse());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the LanguageExt Code where I need some help: How do I "lift" the `sum` function into something, so that `Apply` can use it similar to the previous example?

```cs
using System;
using FluentAssertions;
using LanguageExt;
using LanguageExt.UnitTesting;
using Xunit;
using static LanguageExt.Prelude;

namespace DemoTests._2_LanguageExtDemo
{
    public class Demo
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Sum_validation()
        {
            // Arrange
            Func<int, int, int, int> sum = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;

            Func<int, Validation<Error, int>> onlyPositive = i
                => i > 0
                    ? Success<Error, int>(i)
                    : Fail<Error, int>(Error.New("ups"));

            Validation<Error, int> AddNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
            {
                // how to lift `sum` into an applicative which other functions
                // can apply to??
                return null;
            }


            // Act
            var result = AddNumbers(1, 2, 3);

            // Assert
            result.ShouldBeSuccess(x => x.Should().Be(6));
        }
    }

    public class Error : NewType<Error, string>
    {
        public Error(string e) : base(e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample project: https://github.com/draptik/csharp-applicative-validation/tree/v1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at the language-ext tests for Validation and just copied the way [it's done there](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Tests/ValidationTests.cs) in the very last functions:

The resulting test file was:

```
using System;
using FluentAssertions;
using LanguageExt;
using LanguageExt.UnitTesting;
using Xunit;
using static LanguageExt.Prelude;

namespace DemoTests._2_LanguageExtDemo
{
    public class Demo
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Sum_validation()
        {
            // Arrange
            Func<int, int, int, int> sum = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;

            Func<int, Validation<Error, int>> onlyPositive = i
                => i > 0
                    ? Success<Error, int>(i)
                    : Fail<Error, int>(Error.New("ups"));

            Validation<Error, int> AddNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
            {
                return (onlyPositive(a), onlyPositive(b), onlyPositive(c)).Apply(sum);
            }

            // Act
            var result = AddNumbers(1, 2, 3);

            // Assert
            result.ShouldBeSuccess(x => x.Should().Be(6));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Sum_validation_OneError()
        {
            // Arrange
            Func<int, int, int, int> sum = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;

            Func<int, Validation<Error, int>> onlyPositive = i
                => i > 0
                    ? Success<Error, int>(i)
                    : Fail<Error, int>(Error.New("ups"));

            Validation<Error, int> AddNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
            {
                return (onlyPositive(a), onlyPositive(b), onlyPositive(c)).Apply(sum);
            }

            // Act
            var result = AddNumbers(-1, 2, 3);

            // Assert
            result.ShouldBeFail(x => x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(Error.New("ups")));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Sum_validation_ThreeErrors()
        {
            var error = Error.New("ups");

            // Arrange
            Func<int, int, int, int> sum = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;

            Func<int, Validation<Error, int>> onlyPositive = i
                => i > 0
                    ? Success<Error, int>(i)
                    : Fail<Error, int>(error);

            Validation<Error, int> AddNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
            {
                return (onlyPositive(a), onlyPositive(b), onlyPositive(c)).Apply(sum);
            }


            // Act
            var result = AddNumbers(-1, -2, -3);

            // Assert
            result.ShouldBeFail(x => x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new System.Collections.Generic.List<Error>{ error, error, error }));
        }
    }

    public class Error : NewType<Error, string>
    {
        public Error(string e) : base(e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Excellent.